# Where to get crypto data without survivorship-bias (delisted coins accounted for)?

Tags: data, historical-data, cryptocurrency

What are folks using for their crypto data needs.

I am looking for a provider of Crypto data - free of survivorship bias and should at least have the top 20 coins historically.

As this research paper states, survivorship and delisting bias are a big deal in crypto.
Survivorship and Delisting Bias in Cryptocurrency Markets:
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4287573
"Our results suggest that the survivorship and delisting bias are important biases that ought to be omitted.”

I am comfortable with programming too so if you know of any decent solution out there that I can use, that would be great.

Many Thanks. And Happy New Year!

Comment: no, it doesnt unfortunately. I had a look but the sites either dont have complete data for crypto or its coming soon per their page!

Comment: are you willing to pay?

Comment: yes, but not a huge amount. max $100/month.